# assigning multiple users to a task using Apex Code

Tags: apex, tasks

I need to create a new task by using Apex Code and I want to set "Assign To" field with multiple users and "Notify Assignee" field to 'true'.
But I don't know how to do that by using Apex Code.
Could anyone help me!

Comment: Based on the undelivered [Really assign one task to multiple users](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaview?id=087300000006wbuAAA) it looks like you have to create a Task for each user.